# what is a "damage request" in wayland?

Tags: linux, wayland

I'm learning the wayland protocol with this [tutorial](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/docs/html/), and they keep talking about "damage request" that the client sends to the compositor. What are they exactly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Wayland,

> > wl_surface_dmage(surface-local x coordinate,surface-local y coordinate,width of damage rectangle,height of damage rectangle)

wl_surface_dame actually an event sent by the client to the server with parameters as above, indicating the server to redraw only the specified area and not the whole surface. 
The compositor receives the event and then processes it accordingly, usually by redrawing the specified area.
Initially, the wayland client will use the entire surface as the initial area, send the damage, and draw the surface at the time